# JPA No property findAll found for type Product

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-criteria

My repository：

```
@Repository
public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

   Page<Product> findAll(Specification<Product> specification,Pageable pageable);
}
```

My service:

```
    ...  
@Autowired
        public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository repository, ProductDao productDao, ProductImgService productImgService, ProductClassService productClassService, AuthUserService authUserService, DeviceService deviceService){
        super(repository);
            this.productDao = productDao;
            this.productImgService = productImgService;
            this.productClassService = productClassService;
            this.authUserService = authUserService;
            this.deviceService = deviceService;
        }

        final
        ProductDao productDao; 
...
```

I use it in the service like this:

```
midResult = productDao.findAll((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("ouId").as(Long.class),product.getOuId()));
            if(product.getPclassId()!=null)
                list.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("pclassId").as(Long.class),product.getPclassId()));
            if(product.getProductStatus()!=null)
                list.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("productStatus").as(Integer.class),product.getProductStatus()));
            if(product.getProductName()!=null)
                list.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("productName").as(String.class),product.getProductName()));
            if(product.getCreator()!=null)
                list.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("creator").as(Integer.class),product.getCreator()));
            list.add(criteriaBuilder.between(root.get("createTimeTmp").as(Long.class),Long.parseLong(finalStarttsp),Long.parseLong(finalEndtsp)));
            Predicate[] p = new Predicate[list.size()];
            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(list.toArray(p)));
            return criteriaQuery.getRestriction();
        }, pageable);
```

The Product Class definition is good .

And when I run this code , error turned out to be :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Product!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mybatis.repository.query.PartTreeMybatisQuery.<init>(PartTreeMybatisQuery.java:81) ~[spring-data-mybatis-1.0.17.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mybatis.repository.query.MybatisQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MybatisQueryLookupStrategy.java:71) ~[spring-data-mybatis-1.0.17.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mybatis.repository.query.MybatisQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MybatisQueryLookupStrategy.java:120) ~[spring-data-mybatis-1.0.17.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mybatis.repository.query.MybatisQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MybatisQueryLookupStrategy.java:50) ~[spring-data-mybatis-1.0.17.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mybatis.repository.support.MybatisRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MybatisRepositoryFactoryBean.java:64) ~[spring-data-mybatis-1.0.17.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

I'm using springboot and there's no config like @EnableJpaRepositories 
But it don't seems to be necessary cause other repository is good .

Answer (score 1):

You are using spring-data in incorrect way. When you write method *findAll* in repository, it will look for given attribute in entity.

For example, you have an entity *User* with attribute *firstName*. Then you can defined method like, *findByFirstName*.

In given example, spring-data looking for attribute *all* which is not available as a part of *Product*.

In this case, you need to write your own query using *@Query* annotation.

BTW, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but when I remove the findAll() method in repository,it's still the same error.                                                                                                            And I'm trying to use Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable); in the interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> , can you teach me how to use it ? or just give me some example ?

Answer (score 0):

It works like this for me:

```
@NonNull
Page<Product> findAll(@Nullable Specification<Product> specification, @NonNull Pageable pageable);
```